# Map a json response to an object - Angular

Tags: json, angular, object, get, observable

I have this class:

```
export class Person { 
    constructor(
        public url: string,
        public name: string,
        public gender: string,
        public culture: string,
        public aliases: string[]
   ) {}
}
```

I'm trying to get an Array of type Person with a get function to an open API (JSONPlaceHolder).

In my person.component.ts I have the method:

```
getPeople(): void {
    this.myService.getPeople().subscribe(people: Person[]) => 
        this.allPeople = people
}
```

And in the service:

```
getPeople(): Observable<Person[]>{
    return this.http.get('url of the api').pipe(map((r: any) => 
        r.results.map((p: any) => 
            new Person(p.id, p.name, p.username, p.email)
        )
    ))
}
```

but I don't get anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: share Person class code

Comment: did it right now!

Comment: You are passing 4 params in new Person() instead of 5

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to map `Person` to `Person`? And the values for creating `Person` instance don't match with the constructor. For example, you try to map id to url, username to gender, which is weird.